# Asp.Net Rating Control

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, client-side

I can't get the `ASP.NET` Rating control's selected `value(CurrentValue)` in javascript. I am using Rating control in `datagrid` and do anyone know how can I get the `CurrentValue` of `ASP.NET` Rating in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide any code snippet of Javascript where you want to use the current value of Rating control? 
I think, You might need to set the values in hidden valriables and send the variable names in the form of an array to Javascript in the following way:

1. In the RowDataBound Event of the DataGrid

   ```
   AjaxControlToolkit.Rating objRatingControl= (AjaxControlToolkit.Rating)row.FindControl("objRatingControl");
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("RatingControlIDs", "'" + objRatingControl.ClientID + "'");
   ```
2. Now you can use this array of Rating controls in Javascript.